# How to create a div header angled at top of page

Tags: html, css, header

```
body margin&padding = 0;
```

the div goes out of the viewport

```
<div id="banner" style="    
height: 800px;
width: 100%;
transform: rotate(165deg);
background-color: #f00;
position: absolute;
top: -400px;
left: -50px;
"></div>
```

Comment: an img with the expected output will be really nice .

Comment: even better (because an image is often not useful for frontend stuff) would be more of the code context

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap it in an other div and set overflow hidden

```css
body{margin:0}
```

```html
<div style="position: relative; width: 100%; height: 300px; overflow: hidden; ">
  <div id="banner" style="    
                          height: 500px;
                          width: 200%;
                          transform: rotate(165deg);
                          background-color: #f00;
                          position: absolute;
                          top: -400px;
                          left: -100px;
                          "></div>
  </div>
```

Comment: yes but i want it inside the viewport now you can scroll to the right and i dont want that